# Problem with context in Android Application

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I am writing something to read a Json in Android with Kotlin.

I could write the Json without any Problem, but when I want to read it I got a problem with the "context", because it cant find any context reference.

The Goal is to either start the ChooseLoginActicity if there is no User.Json available or to otherwise read the Json and start the MainActivity.

```
class Launcher : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var textView: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher)
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView)
        readJsonFile()
    }

    fun readJsonFile() {
        val json: String?
        try {
            val inputStream = context.openFileInput("User.json")

            json = inputStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
            val gson = Gson()
            val user = gson.fromJson(json, User::class.java)

            CurrentUser.initUser(user.id,user.name)

            startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
        } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
            startActivity(Intent(this, ChooseLoginActivity::class.java))
        }
    }
```

Comment: An `Activity` *is* a `Context`.

Comment: Basically because you're in an `Activity`, you can use `this` for the `Context`, as in `this.openFileInput`. And since you can omit `this`, you can just write `openFileInput("User.json")`

Comment: You shouldn't read files on the main thread. Read here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads#WorkerThreads

Comment: well in ```fun readJsonFile(context:Context)``` i think this should work for you then ```readJsonFile(this)```

Comment: @TanishqChawda It doesn't make sense for a class to pass itself to its own function. I mean, it will work, but it's kind of nonsensical.

Comment: @Tenfour04 what should be correct way....my solution was just  approach!!

Comment: @TanishqChawda Compare these two classes. Your suggestion is like the complicated version. It has extra unnecessary complexity. https://pl.kotl.in/vCfXRpoCS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change `context.openFileInput("User.json")` to `openFileInput("User.json")`.